# python-AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python

I have a 3D list in python like:

```
features= [ [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ,None , [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],
        [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], None,None,[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ]
```

I expect to see:

```
features=[ [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ,[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],
               [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ,[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ]
```

When I try to remove `None` using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(features)):
if features[i]==None:
    features[i].remove()
```

It produces the error :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'

If I try this:

```
for i in range(len(features)):
if features[i]==None:
    del features[i]
```

It produces error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Lastly I tried this code:

```
for i in range(len(features)):
if features[i]==None:
    features[i]=filter(None,features[i])
```

It produced the error :-

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

How can I fix this error?

Comment: **Do not alter a list you are iterating over at that moment**...

Comment: Template answer: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code block, you are not passing a value to be removed from the list. In the second code block, you are altering the list while iterating, thus producing a skewed index-vs-value location. The best way is to filter out the `None`s from the list:

```
features= [ [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ,None , [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],
    [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]], None,None,[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ]
final_features = list(filter(lambda x:x is not None, features))
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: @ArshadAhmad glad to help! If this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list comprehension and only keep the values if the index is not None, it will keep your sub-lists intact:

```
features = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], None, [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], None, None, [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]

>>> print features 
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], None, [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], None, None, [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]

>>> print [f for f in features if f is not None]
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:

```
features_x = list(filter(None, features))
print(features_x)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/C5f38t).

Comment: i have already tried that i got, ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @ArshadAhmad: Than you have tried sth. else, see the demo, the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Like willem says you should never alter a list that you're iterating over. The correct way of doing is to create a new list. You can do that with a list comprehension in the following way.

```
 New = [item for item in mylist if item is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try it this way:

```
new_features = []

for f in features:
    if f is not None:
        new_features.append(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just index through the array backwards when you do your features[i].remove().

```py
    for i in reversed(range(len(features))):
        if features[i]==None:
            features[i].remove()
```

This way you are not removing array items out from underneath your index.

The other answers are slick-code, no doubt, but this is the easiest simple-code solution.

Of course, you should never alter a list you are iterating through as a general best-practice, but when you absolutely have to keep using the same list, this will work.